# VueJS npm run serve working on Chrome and Firefox but not on Safari and IE

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, babeljs

Here's my .browserslistrc file

```
> 1%
last 2 versions
ie 11
Safari 9
```

Now after I do `npm run serve` it still doesn't work on Safari... I'm testing it on IE by using Safari development mode and setting the User Agent to IE 11.

Anyways The error that I get is:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. Expected an identifier name in const declaration.`

Any insight would be appreciated.